# how to call curl command from oracle plsql?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have the following cURL request (to get token access) that I want to make in PL/SQL :

```
curl -d 'username=admin&password=admin' 'http://xx.x.xx.xx:3080/login/'
```

How i can call this to Getting Token and save the result in table , the response from above look like

```
{"accessToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsInRva2VuIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiyLCJleHAiOjE2MDMxODgxMDJ9.Qh1f1NLX2NllAzV_5bi1X_tnslTet0gaolzRWAzWam0","rstToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsInRva2VuIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImlhdCI6MTYwMzE4NDUwMiwiZXhwIjoxNjAzNzg5MzAyfQ.mByW0yldjgskYmYOP9AG5KMN4ct9mjTDKLzKNAYyKmE"}
```

Comment: Do you insist to use `curl`? Otherwise you can make the http-call with  [UTL_HTTP](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_http.htm#ARPLS070)

Comment: when execute command in linux server it's executed successfully but the below when try that by below answer the result is   (you don't have access please send the password and username or token)

Answer (score 2):

You can make HTTP calls directly with package [UTL_HTTP](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_http.htm#ARPLS070). Could be similar to this one (not tested):

```
DECLARE
   http_request    UTL_HTTP.REQ;
   http_response   UTL_HTTP.RESP;
   
   msg VARCHAR2(32767) := 'username=admin&password=admin';
   url VARCHAR2(1000) := 'http://xx.x.xx.xx:3080/login/';
   token VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN
    
   http_request := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(url, 'POST', UTL_HTTP.HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
   UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset="utf-8"');
   UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(http_request, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(msg));
   UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT(http_request, msg);

   http_response := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(http_request);
   UTL_HTTP.READ_TEXT(http_response, token, 1000);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'token = ' || token );

END;
```

Comment: thanks i trying that but the  response is (you don't have access  please send the password and username or token)

Comment: Maybe try `GET` with url `http://xx.x.xx.xx:3080/login?username=admin&password=admin`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a job of type 'executable':

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(...);
DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(...)
DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(...);
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB(...)
```

Details: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html#GUID-7E744D62-13F6-40E9-91F0-1569E6C38BBC

Answer (score 0):

If curl is on the database server, you can call this or any other executable.
There are various solutions, e.g. https://sourceforge.net/projects/plsqlexecoscomm/

Care needs to be taken to ensure that not ANY command can be run....

We use this technique successfully, since UTL_HTTP has let us down quite often, with various scenarios involving certificates that we haven't even been able to resolve with Oracle Support.

To make the call easier, I find it useful to follow these general steps.

- Write curl parameters to a config file, and not as part of the command line (the Java that calls the O/S struggles with some special characters)
- Write the output / headers to a file, and not stdout.  This way, it is easier to process them in PL/SQL using UTL_FILE and BFILENAME() on an "ORACLE DIRECTORY".
- Ensure the name of your files are unique, using a sequence, GUID etc.  This would be the names of your "config" and "output" file.
- You would then call curl with something like /bin/curl --config #CONFIG_FILE#
  Where #CONFIG# file is the (unique) name of your config file.
- A typical config file

  ```
    url = "your URL"
    output = "unique-file.dat"
    silent
    show-error
    max-time = 30
    -X GET
  ```